# Issue with TS2307 error in typescript compiling.

Tags: typescript, angular

I am having a problem compiling my project. I keep getting `app - Copy/some.component.ts(6,32): error TS2307`. The compiler works, it compiles the typescript and I can either run it on a Windows IIS 7.5 server or I can use `npm run lite` in the project root directory and it will run the application. The problem is my script in my package.json i use to compile and keep listening for changes to files and then run the lite-server doesn't work because of the errors I receiveduring `npm run tsc`. Also as a note when building the project in Atom I get the same errors.

Thanks in advance.

Command Line error print out

```
> OPI-Training@1.0.0 tsc C:\inetpub\wwwroot\OPI-Training-Angular2
> tsc

app - Copy/app.component.ts(6,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module './logon/logon.component'.
app - Copy/app.component.ts(7,35): error TS2307: Cannot find module './employee/employee.component'.
app - Copy/components/logon/logon.component.ts(3,29): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../user.service'.

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run
" "tsc"
npm ERR! node v6.2.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.9.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! OPI-Training@1.0.0 tsc: `tsc`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the OPI-Training@1.0.0 tsc script 'tsc'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the OPI-Training package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     tsc
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs OPI-Training
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls OPI-Training
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\inetpub\wwwroot\OPI-Training-Angular2\npm-debug.log
PS C:\inetpub\wwwroot\OPI-Training-Angular2>
```

Here is a screen shot of my folder structure.

[image: Screen Shot of folder structure]

Here is my tsconfig.ts

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  }
}
```

Here is the script in my package.json file

```JSON
"scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
```

and finally the imports in their respective files

app.components.ts

```
import { UserService } from '../../services/users/user.service';
import { LogonComponent } from '../logon/logon.component';
import { EmployeeComponent } from '../employee/employee.component';
```

logon.components.ts

```
import { UserService } from '../../../app/services/users/user.service';
```

Comment: Well it can't find your imports, did you copy and paste them from another ts file? The routes aren't pointing to anything or they can't be found

Comment: That is the thing it is finding them. If i change one of the imports Get something the same three errors but also this.  `app/components/app/app.component.ts(6,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module './logon/logon.component'.` if I change it back it this error goes away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the issue. I made a back up of my original app folder. Hence the "app - Copy" not thinking anything about it. What was happening was `npm run tsc` was compiling the folder I copied as a back up, and that was where the errors were coming from. Noob mistake.